# How much does the INC instruction in x86 assembly add?

Tags: assembly, x86

Does the INC command used on registers increments by 1 byte or by 4 bytes?

For example, first I set mov ecx,0 and then inc ecx.
what does ecx hold?

Example number 2: esi holds an address in memory.
What happens in this case?

I think that in the first case is 4 bytes and in the second its 1 byte (because memory), am I right?

Comment: It increments by 1. It's clearly written in any instruction set reference.

Comment: @Jester did you mean both examples?

Comment: Yes, `inc` has no idea whether that's an address or not. It's just a 32 bit number, `1` is added, end of story.

Comment: links to guides and manuals at [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  The Intel insn ref manual documents the operation of every instruction with full detail.

Comment: "Example number 2: esi holds an address in memory. What happens in this case?" Nothing when you don't execute `inc` or other instructions. If you are supposed to execute `inc`, what is the operand? Register? Memory? If it is memory., which size?

Comment: bits is bits, as far as adding, subtracting, etc.  it is not an address, it is just a collection of bits.  it only becomes an address when it is used as an address, and then it becomes a collection of bits again.

Comment: As a suggestion, when you have a question like this, why don't you try it yourself before asking?  This is a very elementary question.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: while I fully agree, I have the impression that people who need to ask this probably don't know how to use a debuggger yet, so they don't know how to check this. I personally think that one should not try to do assembler before one knows some basics, but hey, that's just me.

Comment: @David Hoelzer I really don't know how to test this. About an integer its obvious but when It comes to addresses I didn't understand how to print the addresses of esi before and after incrementing it by one.. that's the reason I needed your help

Answer (score 2):

In x86, after you set `ecx` to zero and then do `inc ecx`, the register `ecx` will hold the value `1`. The `inc` mnemonic increments by a step of `1`, regardless of register passed as operand, and regardless of the size of that register.

Answer (score 2):

`inc` :increment , it increments the register value by +1. for example:

```
add eax, 1;
```

we can write it inc eax;

Comment: Not completely the same as INC doesn’t touch the CF as does using ADD to increment a value by one. A bit of a nitpick but also kind of important as it allows iterations in a loop without messing with flags that are set by different calculations you don’t want to be touched.